# Book about security in web applications

Tags: professional-education

I'm new to security in web applications.I have searched in amazon but I was unable to find a book for today's technology. As far as I know HTML5 comes with a few new attack vectors, most of the books didn't include HTML5 vulnerabilities. I'm asking for book that covers most of the things in today technology. I saw a lot of old books(2007-2010) that looked good but they are old now and I'm not sure will I get most of the things I need to know. Probably most of you will say practice well I have complete the challenges in EnigmaGroup and HackThisSite, I have exploited all  vulneravilibies in DVWA. However I can't use any tools all exploitations I made were made manually without any help(except a few firefox plugins), so it will be good if the book covers some tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the following links are not to a book, they are resources to HTML5 and its security:

http://www.slideshare.net/shreeraj/top-10-html5-threats-whitepaper
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet

The following URL is a link to an e-book which can be purchased:

http://developerpress.com/HTML5Security-175296

And another one:

http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781466565319

Have you even tried using a search engine to find books regarding HTML5 security?

Comment: I'm not asking about only HTML5. I'm asking about book to introduce me the security of web apps, the tools used and so on. Anyway thank you for you answer especially the slideshare.